# How to retrieve all ACLs in loopback js?

Tags: loopbackjs

In my ACLs there are some rules(acl) defined for the particular user.

From explorer or angular frontend how to get all acls of a particular user?

I have tried from explorer :

```
URL : http://localhost:3000/api/ACLs?filter=
{"where":{"principalId":"5a817425e09bdb38f9217c20"}} // []
```

Something I am missing or other alternative is there.

Someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't the principalId of a user be the `user`'s `id`?  It looks like you're using the `access_token`'s id

Answer (score 0):

From my API explorer (Loopback 3) the endpoint should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/a-c-ls?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22principalId%22%3A%221%22%7D%7D
```

Also, as for icecream_hobbit comment, I believe you're querying the wrong value of `principalId`.